# New compose version 1.4.3 gives a weird error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, version

Okey so when i start a new project with sdk 33 in android studio everything is fine. I go into the gradle of the app and see that the versiuon of compose are not the newest version. If i update them to the newest version though i get an error that says

```
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

I have no clue why but is the new version of compose to unstable or do i have the wrong jdk i have no clue it just gives me this error trying to switch any version of anything either gives me the same error or a new one... Anyone knows why this happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using compose version `1.4.3`, you should use the latest Kotlin version `1.8.21` and compose compiler version `1.4.7`. Please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) documentation for compose version compatibility.

In your project `build.gradle` file:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.21" apply false
}
```

In your app `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.7"
    }
}
```

You may need to upgrade your Android Grade Plugin and Java version too.